# Pass string to `it` dynamically from a fixture?

Tags: cypress

I want to dynamically pass a string to `it` from a fixture (which resolves to `permissionsObj`). Please see line A in code.

`dynamic string = some__static__string + ${headerPerms}`

and

`headerPerms = permissionsObj['header'];`

But somehow I am getting `headerPerms` undefined when passed to `it`

**Code:**

**line A:** headerPerms is undefined.

**line B:** headerPerms logs successfully.

Is there anyway I can pass string to `it` dynamically from a fixture?

```
describe(`role based testing:: header`, function () {
    let headerPerms;
    before(() => {
        cy.fixture('../fixtures/permissions').then((permissionsObj) => {
            headerPerms = permissionsObj['header'];
        });
        cy.wait(1000);
    });

    it(`checks if dashboard_KB exists:: ${headerPerms}`, function () { // line A: headerPerms is undefined
        cy.log(headerPerms);//Line B: logs successfully
    });
});
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**fixture:**

```
{
  "header": {
    "dashboard_nav": {
      "admin": true,
      "developer": true,
      "analyst": true,
      "tester": true
    },
    "dashboard_KB": {
      "admin": true,
      "developer": true,
      "analyst": false,
      "tester": false
    },
    "dashboard_analytics": {
      "admin": true,
      "developer": true,
      "analyst": true,
      "tester": false
    },
    "dashboard_reports": {
      "admin": true,
      "developer": true,
      "analyst": false,
      "tester": false
    },
    "header-profile": {
      "admin": true,
      "developer": true,
      "analyst": true,
      "tester": true
    },
    "header-enterprise-profile": {
      "admin": true,
      "developer": false,
      "analyst": false,
      "tester": false
    },
    "header-sign-out": {
      "admin": true,
      "developer": true,
      "analyst": true,
      "tester": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain your object values like that. Basically you are losing the context and hence you are seeing the header value as undefined.

use below code snippet which will work like charm.

```
const fixtures = require("../fixtures/headersJsonFile");
describe('feature', function () {

    const headers = Object.keys(fixtures.header);
    headers.forEach(header => {
        it(`header ${header} test`, () => {
            cy.log('', header);
        });
    });

});
```

I have verified and it is working....Below is the output for the same.

```
  feature
    ✓ header dashboard_nav test
    ✓ header dashboard_KB test
    ✓ header dashboard_analytics test
    ✓ header dashboard_reports test
    ✓ header header-profile test
    ✓ header header-enterprise-profile test
    ✓ header header-sign-out test
```